# How can I make a field appears when you check on a checkbox?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm making a module and on the administration page there is a form and I want to make one of the fields appears only when user check on a checkbox. Like the option to add a new content to a menu.

Comment: Please add the code snippet of the custom module for better understanding.

Comment: It's a normal form ,,, $form[]

Comment: the simplest method, without having to get into ajax callbacks, etc - is to add the elements to the form from the start, and then a bit of jquery to hide, and then show the element you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use #states from FormAPI that drupal provides.
Below is the link
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states

Below is the code from drupal form api

```
$form['email_canceled']['settings'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#states' => array(
      // Hide the settings when the cancel notify checkbox is disabled.
      'invisible' => array(
       ':input[name="email_canceled_toggle"]' => array('checked' => FALSE),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use like this

```
$form['field_image']['#states']['visible'] = array(':input[name="field_checkbox[und]"]' => array('value' => 1));
```

so only when the check box is checked the field image will be displayed otherwise it will be hidden.